# Why does GitKraken crash after my last Fedora 36 update?

Tags: fedora, gitkraken

I enjoyed using GitKraken (v8.9) until I updated my current Fedora 36 distribution.

After the update, I had the problem that GitKraken crashed every time I wanted to open a repository tab or when I wanted to open the "File/Settings..." view.

I've updated GitKraken to the latest version and also looked at what the Fedora update includes, which may have caused the problem.

Additionally, I collected the coredump of the crash (via `coredumpctl gdb` and the crash log via `journalctl -xf`)

```
  Command Line: $'/usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken --type=renderer --enable-crashpad --crashpad-handler-pid=3178 --enable-crash-reporter=dde15cd3-eccc-4db0-abbf-4626ba853f5f,no_channel --user-data-dir=/home/hugo/.config/GitKraken --standard-schemes --secure-schemes --bypasscsp-schemes=sentry-ipc --cors-schemes=sentry-ipc --fetch-schemes=sentry-ipc --service-worker-schemes --streaming-schemes --app-path=/usr/share/gitkraken/resources/app.asar --no-sandbox --no-zygote --node-integration-in-worker --disable-gpu-compositing --lang=en-US --num-raster-threads=4 --enable-main-frame-before-activation --renderer-client-id=9 --launch-time-ticks=54958457852 --shared-files=v8_context_snapshot_data:100 --field-trial-handle=0,890488252484140780,4810308880598401477,131072 --disable-features=PlzServiceWorker,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess --enable-crashpad'
    Executable: /usr/share/gitkraken/gitkraken
 Control Group: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/app.slice/app-gnome-gitkraken-2553.scope
          Unit: user@1000.service
     User Unit: app-gnome-gitkraken-2553.scope
         Slice: user-1000.slice
     Owner UID: 1000 (hugo)
       Boot ID: 8bdd7f9dd7194682b2286579c96c8ec7
    Machine ID: 70b436a43d284e9f9e7f1073bc0cf15b
      Hostname: tag009442760151
       Storage: /var/lib/systemd/coredump/core.gitkraken.1000.8bdd7f9dd7194682b2286579c96c8ec7.56008.1667909034000000.zst (present)
     Disk Size: 77.8M
       Message: Process 56008 (gitkraken) of user 1000 dumped core.
                
                Module linux-vdso.so.1 with build-id 28de22885e5a5f761e8b05fe6d610d65bb875b04
                Module nsfw.node without build-id.
                Module libxkbfile.so.1 with build-id e9e99444598d67ff8514b6adfb390156611311d6
                Stack trace of thread 56072:
                #0  0x00007f26c336cffc __strlen_evex (libc.so.6 + 0x16cffc)
                #1  0x00007f26bf3d351e _ZN14FontDescriptorC2EPKcS1_S1_S1_10FontWeight9FontWidthbb (fontmanager.node + 0xb51e)
                #2  0x00007f26bf3d8f19 _Z20createFontDescriptorP10_FcPattern (fontmanager.node + 0x10f19)
                #3  0x00007f26bf3d8fb9 _Z12getResultSetP10_FcFontSet (fontmanager.node + 0x10fb9)
                #4  0x00007f26bf3d9182 _ZN15FontManagerImpl17getAvailableFontsEPP9ResultSet (fontmanager.node + 0x11182)
                #5  0x00007f26bf3d7c7e _ZN18PromiseAsyncWorkerI9ResultSetE7ExecuteEv (fontmanager.node + 0xfc7e)
                #6  0x00005602f9af87c1 n/a (gitkraken + 0x20257c1)
                #7  0x00007f26c328cded start_thread (libc.so.6 + 0x8cded)
                #8  0x00007f26c3312370 __clone3 (libc.so.6 + 0x112370)
```

With this information I contacted GitKraken support. The information I got from them is that it's a known issue that GitKraken can't handle some custom fonts, and the most common culprit is JetBrains fonts.

I also got a list of certain fonts that are known to cause problems viz

- RedHatFont
- JetBrains Mono font on Fedora 34 and Ubuntu 20.04 (see comments on this issue).
- Vazir
- Rubik

I didn't have any of these fonts installed, so it wasn't applicable to me.

Does someone face the same problem and has a solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

I played around a bit with reverting packages I updated with in the buggy update, taking into account the information that *GitKraken* is having issues with some custom fonts.

And finally, I found a bunch of fonts related to the *wine* package that **fixed the problem** on rollback.

I didn't actually do the rollback, but completely uninstalled all *wine* related fonts because I don't need them anyway.

Removing following fonts solved my problem:

```
$ sudo dnf remove wine-\*-fonts
Dependencies resolved.
=====================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                        Architecture               Version                                Repository                    Size
=====================================================================================================================================================
Removing:
 wine-arial-fonts                               noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                     157 k
 wine-courier-fonts                             noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                     170 k
 wine-fixedsys-fonts                            noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                      37 k
 wine-marlett-fonts                             noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                      32 k
 wine-ms-sans-serif-fonts                       noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                     4.6 M
 wine-small-fonts                               noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                      65 k
 wine-symbol-fonts                              noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                      51 k
 wine-system-fonts                              noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                     121 k
 wine-tahoma-fonts                              noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                     300 k
 wine-times-new-roman-fonts                     noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                     170 k
 wine-webdings-fonts                            noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                      30 k
 wine-wingdings-fonts                           noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                      35 k
Removing dependent packages:
 wine-fonts                                     noarch                     7.19-1.fc36                            @updates                       0  
Removing unused dependencies:
 liberation-narrow-fonts                        noarch                     2:1.07.6-8.fc36                        @fedora                      504 k

Transaction Summary
=====================================================================================================================================================
Remove  14 Packages
```

BTW, the 'old' (rollback) version of these *wine* fonts where *GitKraken* still worked was `7.12-2`, but I haven't explicitly tried this rollback alone.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around I found, that the problem might be loading fonts.
There is a support request ( might be done already ): https://feedback.gitkraken.com/suggestions/218000/add-ligature-font-support

With that hint I installed fira-code-fonts from the repository and this solved my problem to open preferences.

My System:

- Gitkraken 8.10.3
- Fedora 36